# Setting Midpoint for continuous diverging color scale on a heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I need to adjust the midpoint location for a heatmap via ggplot2.  I've googled around and have seen `scale_fill_gradient2` be a great fit but the colors don't seem to match up to what I'm looking for.  I know z needs a range from 0 to 1.  Example dataset generation below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(5)
df <- as_tibble(expand.grid(x = -5:5, y = 0:5, z = NA))
df$z <- runif(length(df$z), min = 0, max = 1)
```

I tried plotting with the `scale_fill_gradient2` but the blue color isn't coming as "dark" as I'd like.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = 'red', mid = 'white', high = 'blue',
    midpoint = 0.7, guide = 'colourbar', aesthetics = 'fill'
  ) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$x)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$y))
```

[image: Version 1]

Therefore, I'm using `scale_fill_distiller` with the color palette 'RdBu' which comes out with the color scale I need but the ranges and the midpoints aren't right.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'RdBu') + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$x)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$y))
```

[image: Version 2]

Is there a way to get the 2nd color scale but with the option to set midpoint range as the first?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I think that the problem is that the range taken for the colors is -5 to 5. and the range of z is 0 to 1. I would of checked it myself, but I'm having trouble with ggplot at the moment. Try changing `geom_tile(aes(fill = z))` to `geom_tile(aes(fill = (z*10 - 5)))`

Comment: That's a good point.  Unfortunately, I still have that problem.  I have an idea though and maybe just building two continuous gradients and stitching them together might be efficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The color scales provided by the colorspace package will generally allow you much more fine-grained control. First, you can use the same colorscale but set the mid-point.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(colorspace)

set.seed(5)
df <- as_tibble(expand.grid(x = -5:5, y = 0:5, z = NA))
df$z <- runif(length(df$z), min = 0, max = 1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) + 
  scale_fill_continuous_divergingx(palette = 'RdBu', mid = 0.7) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$x)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$y))
```

[image]

However, as you see, this creates the same problem as before, because you'd have to be further away from the midpoint to get darker blues. Fortunately, the divergingx color scales allow you to manipulate either branch independently, and so we can create a scale that turns to dark blue much faster. You can play around with `l3`, `p3`, and `p4` until you get the result you want.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) + 
  scale_fill_continuous_divergingx(palette = 'RdBu', mid = 0.7, l3 = 0, p3 = .8, p4 = .6) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$x)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$y))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow this is perfect!  This is exactly what I've been having an issue with.  I'll be applying this method to my code.  Thanks!

Comment: For the `scale_fill_continuous_divergingx` I've been reading `l3`, `p3`, and `p4` input values (specifically https://rdrr.io/rforge/colorspace/man/divergingx_hcl.html ) but I can't seem to wrap my head around that.  What if I have values that range larger than 0 to 1?  Will those values accept numbers that are higher than the range given?  Or similar to what @teunbrand wrote for his solution does this need to be a range from 0 to 1 based on an index?

Comment: Don, if you have a follow-up question about `scale_fill_contiuous_diverginx()`, that’s probably better posted as a separate top-level question.

Comment: Claus, thanks!  I was about to do that as well.  Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 8):

Claus' answer is great (and I'm a fan of his work), but I'd like to add that you can retain control within vanilla ggplot as well if you use the `scale_fill_gradientn()` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

set.seed(5)
df <- as_tibble(expand.grid(x = -5:5, y = 0:5, z = NA))
df$z <- runif(length(df$z), min = 0, max = 1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = c("red", "white", "blue"),
    values = c(0, 0.7, 1)
  ) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$x)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = unique(df$y))
```

[image]

A notable downside is that you'd have to provide the `values` argument in rescaled space, so between 0-1. Consider if your fill values range from 0-10 instead and want the midpoint on 0.7, you'd have to provide `values = c(0, 0.07, 1)`.

Comment: You know I was looking at `scale_fill_gradientn()` but I thought that wouldn't be the right function to use.  But this is also a solid and easier-to-use solution.  Thanks!