# Setting custom labels on stacked ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

This question is a continuation of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718527/setting-midpoint-for-continuous-diverging-color-scale-on-a-heatmap).

I have a heatmap with a dataset available.  The dataset is pasted below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(colorspace)
library(directlabels)

smalltest <- structure(list(x = c(-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
                                  -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -8, 
                                  -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -8, -7, 
                                  -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -8, -7, -6, 
                                  -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -8, -7, -6, -5, 
                                  -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
                            y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
                                 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
                            z = c(0.353727812855041, 0.512450876310741, 
                                  0.668920303216554, 0.770942367746301, 0.829915628317595, 0.873001682466956, 
                                  0.900219155289838, 0.918353789896507, 0.936488424503176, 0.954641684205298, 
                                  0.961439844045867, 0.972770110446816, 0.975042372092157, 0.981846740297877, 
                                  0.986385055223408, 0.986385055223408, 0.986385055223408, 0.33104865495769, 
                                  0.464820298870698, 0.62128351741136, 0.752801524774481, 0.804964208774903, 
                                  0.850322524569605, 0.879812259037828, 0.913821683336127, 0.934222371222986, 
                                  0.950109577644919, 0.959173790765678, 0.970504057166626, 0.975042372092157, 
                                  0.981846740297877, 0.986385055223408, 0.986385055223408, 0.986385055223408, 
                                  0.31064175870568, 0.428544821292209, 0.589558771488704, 0.725596468681902, 
                                  0.786835782533385, 0.838986049803505, 0.872995474101805, 0.897946893644497, 
                                  0.920613634811545, 0.943299001074047, 0.956907737485488, 0.970504057166626, 
                                  0.970504057166626, 0.981840531932726, 0.986385055223408, 0.986385055223408, 
                                  0.986385055223408, 0.29023486245367, 0.419493024901753, 0.569145666871543, 
                                  0.702929727514853, 0.775480682671832, 0.827655783402557, 0.866197314261236, 
                                  0.891148733803927, 0.916075319886014, 0.931943901212494, 0.952369422559957, 
                                  0.970504057166626, 0.970504057166626, 0.981840531932726, 0.981840531932726, 
                                  0.986385055223408, 0.986385055223408, 0.272100227847001, 0.396807658639251, 
                                  0.557778150279687, 0.691580836018451, 0.766410261185922, 0.807248887150547, 
                                  0.857126892775325, 0.888876472158586, 0.911543213325635, 0.929684056297455, 
                                  0.941020531063555, 0.959155165670224, 0.968231795521285, 0.977302217007196, 
                                  0.981840531932726, 0.984112793578067, 0.984112793578067, 0.265302068006432, 
                                  0.396789033543797, 0.557784358644838, 0.680244361252351, 0.761871946260391, 
                                  0.800444518944826, 0.841264519813997, 0.882078312318017, 0.909277160045445, 
                                  0.931950109577645, 0.941014322698404, 0.954623059109845, 0.961421218950414, 
                                  0.972763902081665, 0.977302217007196, 0.984112793578067, 0.984112793578067)), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -102L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I can generate a heatmap and contour lines based on the dataset presented above.

```
    ggplot(smalltest, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) + 
      scale_fill_continuous_divergingx(palette = 'RdBu', rev = FALSE, mid = 0.9, l3 = 0, p3 = 0.95, p4 = 0.85) + 
      scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = -8:8) + 
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = 0:5) + 
      geom_contour(aes(z = z), breaks = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95), color = 'black', size = 1) +
      geom_dl(aes(label = c(rep(NA, 99), 'Low', 'Middle', 'High')), method = 'last.points')
```

[image: Heatmap]

I have the following questions:

1. How do I have the `geom_dl()` only look/use the ends or the sides of the contour lines for those labels?  I added the `rep(NA,99)` initially as I get an error stating that the length of `label` must either be equal to 1 or the length of the dataset (102 here).  But how can I simply just pass through a vector of custom strings?
2. How do I extend the contour lines to the ends of the tile?

Thanks!

<sup>Created on 2019-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: 1) maybe simply use `annotate`? 2) setting `ylim` differently, maybe? possibly within a call to `coord`

Comment: Thanks for that recommendation!  I guess that is a possibility.  The issue is that I was hoping to have this be automated, but it's an option.

Comment: As far as I understand your problem, you want to annotate 'programmatically' at the end of the contour lines within the plot? I guess that's not super easy, because it also depends on how you calculate the contour lines. One option could be to find the minima/maxima of your lines/ polygons in the ggproto object and then use those coordinates within the call to annotate. This can be wrapped into a function.